Please help me identify IC - PS63021
please everyone help me identify following IC. ( PS63021)




A better photo would be helpful, as well as a zoomed out photo of the surrounding components. And any hint about what the board is for.

Either you haven't googled the part number PS63021, or you haven't explained in your question why you're still unsure after googling it.

Texas Instruments TPS63021. A book-boost converter with integrated switch.

This is a 14-pin VSON package. The TI is the give away, with the number above being the part number shortened:


It's a TI TPS63021 single-inductor (4-switch) buck-boost converter. Image from lcsc.com

